# Servo driver code makes servo behaving oddly

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to implement driver for servo without using Arduino Libraries. But what I'm achieving is oddly behaving servo, it goes to right but does not want return to 0 degrees. This is my code (it's quick and dirty):

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 180; i++)
  {
    setServo(i);
  }
  for(int i = 180; i > 0; i--)
  {
    setServo(i);
  }
}

void setServo(float angle)
{

  float out = (angle * 2) / 180;
  Serial.println(out);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(out);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(20);
}
```

Where I'm missing point? Could someone tell me some advices how to implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how servos work. First off, they have to have a high pulse from ~700~2300us. A high pulse that is 1500us long will center the servo. Using a delay in ms will NOT work. You must use delayMicroseconds. Additionally, even the slightest time jitter in the pulse will cause a servo to jitter.

So, re-write your code and post it again. You *can* make it work with delayMicroseconds (I've done it), but it will not work well.  I recommend you write your code to make a high pulse of 1000us for "full" in one direction, and 2000us for "full" in the other direction, to start. Once you get it working, you can adjust these values to see what the servo will really accept as full commands in one direction or the other.

Also, be sure to adjust your waiting time after the end of each pulse if you want a consistent complete period of 20ms. Ex: if your high pulse is 1000us, your low time should be 19000us, to keep a steady 50Hz output signal, which is considered to be standard. Look into using the map() function too. I highly recommend you use the Servo library. Why don't you want to use it?

PS. Writing proper servo code takes a great deal of effort and must be done with low-level timers and interrupt service routines.

Comment: I'm just curious. Also knowing how to implement it will help me with using them on other pieces of hardware. I'll post new code tommorow

Comment: That's true; gaining a good low-level understanding is always a good thing. Sounds good. I look forward to seeing what you come up with. I'm editing my answer above to give you a bit more help too.